# How can we change text of Android M permission request dialogue screen?

Tags: android, android-permissions

```
if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// Permission has not been granted and must be requested.
if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Camera access is required to display a camera preview.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

// i want to change the Prompt message here instead of giving toast message 
 Message could be explanatory why permission is needed
    }
}

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible. You are supposed to display your own UI here, though probably not a `Toast`.

Comment: But will it be a good user experience at first place to display one more activity on top of the prompt , i mean user will be seeing to many screens and he will be bored to do any action and ultimately end up doing nothing or probably he will not use the app.

Comment: If "user will be seeing to many screens and he will be bored to do any action and ultimately end up doing nothing or probably he will not use the app", you have bigger problems.

Comment: Here are some examples: http://www.androidcentral.com/run-permissions-why-change-android-60-may-make-you-repeat-yourself

Comment: Thank you :) only way is add a explainatory dialogue before this one .

Comment: Following up on an old question here, is it possible to do this in the latest Android version?